# Initialize Mapbox Map

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I wanted to set an onmarkerclicklistener for the map, but I get:

"Attempttoinvokevirtualmethod'voidcom.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap$OnMarkerClickListener)' on a null object reference"

I guess this is because I haven't initialized the map, but I dont know how to.

Anyone knows? Thanks!

Comment: `MapboxMap` will be `null`. Might be you haven't initialized it.

Comment: Yes i know, i dont know how to initialize it yet

Comment: Show your code !

Answer (score 0):

You can init mapBox with:

```
Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
```

Check [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/overview/)

Comment: I have already done that, what I want to do is initializing the variable map which is a MapboxMap

Comment: Check step "4. Add a map" in documentation

and in method "onMapReady" you can add marker, set listeners etc.